# std::views::transform not working after std::views::chunk

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I'm trying to get all entries in a `std::multimap` where two entries have the same key and then I want to multiply them up.

My idea so far was the following

```
// std::multimap<uint32_t, uint32_t> gears
auto gearRatios = gears
    | std::views::filter([&gears](const auto& pair) { return gears.count(pair.first) == 2; })
    | std::views::transform([&gears](const auto& pair) { return pair.second; })
    | std::views::chunk(2)
    | std::views::transform([](const auto& elements) { return std::accumulate(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 1, [](const auto& acc, const auto& value) { return acc * value; }); });
uint32_t sumOfGearRatios = std::accumulate(gearRatios.begin(), gearRatios.end(), 0);
```

But the compiler complains on the second transform with

```
[build] C:/Users/morit/Git/aoc2023/03/02_EngineSchematics.cpp:135:82: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_InputIterator' ('std::counted_iterator<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:62&)> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:63&)> >::_Iterator<false> >' and 'std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::subrange<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:62&)> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:63&)> >::_Iterator<false>, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:62&)> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:63&)> >::_Iterator<false>, std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized> >::_Sentinel<true>')
[build]   135 |         | std::views::transform([](const auto& elements) { return std::accumulate(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 1, [](const auto& acc, const auto& value) { return acc * value; }); });
[build]       |                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] C:/Users/morit/Git/aoc2023/03/02_EngineSchematics.cpp: In function 'int main()':
[build] C:/Users/morit/Git/aoc2023/03/02_EngineSchematics.cpp:135:9: error: no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'std::ranges::chunk_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:62&)> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:63&)> > >' and 'std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Transform, main()::<lambda(const auto:64&)> >')
[build]   131 |     auto gearRatios = gears
[build]       |                       ~~~~~
[build]   132 |         | std::views::filter([&gears](const auto& pair) { return gears.count(pair.first) == 2; })
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]   133 |         | std::views::transform([&gears](const auto& pair) { return pair.second; })
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]   134 |         | std::views::chunk(2)
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         |
[build]       |         std::ranges::chunk_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:62&)> >, main()::<lambda(const auto:63&)> > >
[build]   135 |         | std::views::transform([](const auto& elements) { return std::accumulate(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 1, [](const auto& acc, const auto& value) { return acc * value; }); });
[build]       |         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |                                |
[build]       |                                std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Transform, main()::<lambda(const auto:64&)> >
```

I'm using

- Windows 10
- GCC 13.1.0 x64 installed through MSYS64
- CMake 3.26.4
- Ninja 1.11.1

Edit:
After implementing all the input from the comments my code now looks like this:

```
// std::multimap<uint32_t, uint32_t> gears
    auto gearRatios = gears
        | std::views::chunk_by([](const auto& pairOne, const auto& pairTwo) { return pairOne.first == pairTwo.first; })
        | std::views::filter([](const auto& chunk) { return chunk.size() == 2; })
        | std::views::transform([](const auto& elements) { return std::ranges::fold_left(elements, 1, [](const auto& acc, const auto& value) { return acc * value; }); });
    uint32_t sumOfGearRatios = std::ranges::fold_left(gearRatios, 0, [](const auto& acc, const auto& value) { return acc + value; });
```

But it once again does not compile since in the filter lambda chunk has no attribute size().
I guess I could sum up all elements via a `fold_left` but is there a more elegant solution?

#### Example input

```
std::multimap<uint32_t, uint32_t> gears{
    {5, 20},
    {5, 30},
    {6, 50},
    {15, 10},
    {15, 5},
    {15, 2}
}
```

#### Expected output

20 * 30 = 600

Comment: `elements` is a view, not a container. One important difference is that `begin()` and `end()` may produce different types (the latter is a sentinel). But `std::accumulate` can't handle that; this is what the error message is trying to say. The range-aware version of `std::accumulate` is [`std::ranges::fold_left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left)

Comment: `gears.count(pair.first) == 2` - ouch. I think I'd rather `chunk_by` equal keys.

Comment: Could you provide the expected input as well as output? I don't quite understand why you would do this.

Comment: N.B. The second `views::transform(...)` can simply be replaced by `views::values`.

Comment: The problem was addressed by Igor. For the sake of readability, reolace first `transform` with `views::values`. Next as black cat suggests, instead of capturing `gears` in lambda, use `views::chunk_by` and `filter` on size, removing the original `filter` and `chunk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subrange`s split by `views::chunk_by` are not `sized_range` in your example, so it does not provide the `size()` member. You need to use `ranges::distance` to calculate their sizes, which is linear time.

In addition, since the element of `subrange`s is key-value pair, you also need to transform them into value ranges:

```
auto gearRatios = gears
    | std::views::chunk_by([](const auto& pairOne, const auto& pairTwo) { return pairOne.first == pairTwo.first; })
    | std::views::filter([](const auto& chunk) { return std::ranges::distance(chunk) == 2; })
    | std::views::transform(std::views::values) // <-- here
    | std::views::transform([](const auto& elements) { return std::ranges::fold_left(elements, 1, std::multiplies{}); });
auto sumOfGearRatios = std::ranges::fold_left(gearRatios, 0, std::plus{});
```

As in your first attempt, it might be concise to filter via `count()` :

```
auto gearRatios = gears
    | std::views::filter([&gears](const auto& pair) { return gears.count(pair.first) == 2; })
    | std::views::values
    | std::views::chunk(2)
    | std::views::transform([](const auto& elements) { return std::ranges::fold_left(elements, 1, std::multiplies{}); });
auto sumOfGearRatios = std::ranges::fold_left(gearRatios, 0, std::plus{});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zTGfEr7cY)